# Loop over a list of environment variables inside the environment directive at start of pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I haven't found any examples of how to do this.

Instead of this

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker' }
    environment {
        ENV1 = 'default'
        ENV2 = 'default'
    }
```

I want to do this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker' }
    environment {
        for (env in envs) {
           env.name = env.value
        }
    }
```

Maybe I can generate a map before the `pipeline{}` directive and pass it to `environment{}` somehow? I don't want to do this inside of a stage, I want this at the top level environment directive for all stages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `environment` directive [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment) it is not possible to execute any code inside the `environment` block, however you can achieve something similar by creating a custom step and updating the relevant environment variables using a `script` block and any groovy code your want for updating the `env` dictionary that contains the environment values.
Something like:

```
 pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker' }
    stages {
        stage('Prepare Environment') {
            steps {
                script{
                    envParams = ['param1': 'value1','param2': 'value2']
                    envParams.each { key ,value ->
                        env[key] = value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This will affect the environment parameters for **all stages in the pipeline** not just the `Prepare Environment` stage.

Another simple option will be just to run a similar code at the top level of the pipeline before execution the starts, it will have the same effect as the previous option, with a somewhat cleaner look for the pipeline itself. Something like:

```
ENV_PARAMS= ['param1': 'value1','param2': 'value2']
ENV_PARAMS.each { key ,value ->
    env[key] = value
}

pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker' }
    ...
}
```

Comment: how do you update env with credential parameters?

Comment: also updating `env` this way does not appear to work. running printenv inside an sh step does not show `param1` or `param2` but it does show the default ones `BRANCH_NAME` etc. `env` is not a simple map did you test this?

Comment: Tested it both in a declarative and a scripted pipeline with `sh 'printenv'` and it worked fine

Comment: i was trying to use env vars with hyphens in the name and bash was ignoring them

Comment: Regarding credentials parameters my method wont work, ill try to think about something